# SSH with no internet

Tags: networking, wireless, ssh

I don't know much about network configuration, but I would like to setup a wifi network in order to ssh between 2 machines running ubuntu. Both machines have their own wifi cards. They will be operating outdoors with no existing wifi or internet access. I am interested in solutions for both short and long range connections. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of network connection between the two devices for ssh to work.

You can ssh to a computer on a local network with:

```
ssh user@computername.local
```

I know this works for devices connected to the same router. I'd presume it's the same situation if you connected the two computers with a cat5/ethernet cable.

Comment: In addition to needing a network connection, you also need to install the openssh-server package on the machines that will be receiving ssh connections, and openssh-client on the machines where you will be running the ssh command. You can install both packages on both machines.

Comment: Thanks T. Zack and John. I've used openssh to connect on existing networks, but it has failed when I have tried to create my own network and ssh over it. I need to connect wirelessly, one computer will be on a drone. From what I've been reading I think the solution will involve using some type of wireless AP to boost the network I create.

Comment: You can try setting up a Wifi hotspot on one of the machines. Ubuntu supports this